# Send Excel files to Office for editing and read changes

Tags: ios, excel, ms-office

Right now I have an Excel file locally in my iOS application and the file is downloaded from our own servers.

I want to be able to edit the Excel file somehow and I can't seem to get my head around how to do it with the Excel app.
I'm aware that you can't edit local files in another app like that, so I tried with links to files on my OneDrive account. I just can't seem to get the url right.

It seems like I need a direct link to the file, but all I get is a guest access link, when I make the file shareable.

Comment: So if you are using your iPhone with a standalone Excel app, and an OneDrive app and an account, you should be able to open the Excel file from OneDrive to Excel app.  Once you click the file inside OneDrive, you should see the Excel icon on top of the file, and just click that should lead you to the Excel app directly.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Google Sheets app? Might do the trick.

Comment: I forgot to add that I want to be able to read the changes after the edit. Do you think it's possible with the Google Sheets app?

Comment: @stonecompass Yeah, I think I used to look at old work schedules on my phone.

Comment: Additional authentication is an issue, so the Google Sheets app is not an option :-( Authentication for Office365 is not an issue though.